# Get access token for ios Dwolla payment sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, dwolla

I am working on Dwolla payment gateway integration.
I have created one sandbox user and created one application and got Client key and secret both. Now if i am generating access token from sandbox account and using it(access token) in my iOS application it works fine and i am able to get balance,account info etc.
I want to generate access token from my iOS application but the method is not working on my side.
can any one help me for this.

I got dwolla sdks from here https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-ios .
According to this, This method should get called when user successful logged in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = (NSMutableURLRequest *)req; 

    NSArray *urlItems = [[request.URL query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableArray *urlValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[urlItems count]];

    for (int i = 0; i<[urlItems count]; i++) 
    {
        NSArray *keysValues = [[urlItems objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [urlValues insertObject:keysValues atIndex:i];
    }

    if([urlValues count]>0 && [self hasCode:urlValues]) 
    {
        [self requestAccessToken:[[urlValues objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and this condition need to be full fill to get access token, but in my case this condition never gets true.

```
if([urlValues count]>0 && [self hasCode:urlValues]) 
    {
        [self requestAccessToken:[[urlValues objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1]];
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue ?? I am really struggling with this !